# Mark node name after adding new node

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, treeview

I have a Telerik `RadTreeView` with an underlying `CollectionViewSource`. When I add a new item to that collection it gets a default name "New Node". I want to set that node into edit mode so the user can immediately enter a new name for that node.

Setting `IsInEditMode` to `true` puts the node into edit mode but does not mark the name. The cursor is simply at the beginning and the current name must be marked first by the user. Is there a possibility to mark the current name automatically?

Snippets from my XAML code:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadTreeViewItem}" >
    <Setter Property="IsInEditMode" Value="{Binding Path=IsInEditMode}"/>
</Style>

<telerik:RadTreeView.ItemEditTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding NodeName, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</telerik:RadTreeView.ItemEditTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{NodeViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding NodeChildren}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding NodeName}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate >
```

The C# code simply sets the property "`IsInEditMode`" of the `NodeViewModel` to `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to handle the `GotKeyboardFocus` event for the `TextBox` in the view:

```
<telerik:RadTreeView.ItemEditTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding NodeName, Mode=TwoWay}" GotKeyboardFocus="TextBox_GotKeyboardFocus" />
    </DataTemplate>
</telerik:RadTreeView.ItemEditTemplate>
```

---

```
private void TextBox_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
    textBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => textBox.SelectAll()), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response - this works. I figured out that simply setting the IsInEditMode property to true does actually work if it is done in the Dispatcher thread or with a System.Threading.Timer with a delay of 1ms. I don't know what happens in the tree but obviously it takes a short time or probably rather a thread change for the tree to refresh. I wonder whether there is a cleaner solution for this.

Comment: The official telerik forum proposes the same: http://www.telerik.com/forums/edit-node-name-after-adding-new-node#ZC0S2WAvXUyJ4XNR63zCuA